# Перевод наносекунд в милисекунды с точкой

Tags: java

Как с помощью `BigDecimal` перевести нано секунды в милисекунды но с точкой, после точки идут наносекунды.

Вот код:

```
BigDecimal timeStart = new BigDecimal(System.nanoTime());

//ОПЕРАЦИИ

BigDecimal result = new BigDecimal(System.nanoTime()).subtract(timeStart);

long m = result.longValue();
```

В результате выходят такие интересные числа 1196999872, а надо перевести нано секунды в милисекунды но с точкой, главное тут точность.

Comment: А в чем проблема через деление и вычитание сделать?

Comment: Вам потом результат "с точкой" надо в строку преобразовать?

Comment: Мне это надо вывести, с точкой да. Вывод конечноже в String

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
BigDecimal timeStart = new BigDecimal(System.nanoTime());
Thread.sleep(999); // некий длительный процесс
BigDecimal nanos = new BigDecimal(System.nanoTime()).subtract(timeStart);
BigDecimal millis = nanos.divide(new BigDecimal(1000000));

System.out.println(nanos);    // 999089474
System.out.println(millis);   // 999.089474
```

> главное тут точность.

Коли так, рекомендую [почитать](http://shipilev.net/blog/2014/nanotrusting-nanotime/) или [послушать](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8pMfUopQ9Es) Алексея Шипилёва о том, какие грабли можно поймать, используя `System.nanoTime()` для измерений.

Comment: Если я сделаю так         result = new BigDecimal(System.nanoTime()).subtract(timeStart).divide(new BigDecimal(1000000)).divide(new BigDecimal(1000));
 я получу в секундах верно? но с точкой после нее остаток милисек?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Comment: Ок, спасибо.  все нормально работает.

Answer (score 0):

Можно еще для красоты воспользоваться форматом:

```
BigDecimal nanoSeconds = BigDecimal.valueOf( 123_456_789_123_456_789L );
BigDecimal milliSeconds = nanoSeconds.scaleByPowerOfTen( -6 );
System.out.println( nanoSeconds );   // 123456789123456789
System.out.println( milliSeconds );  //123456789123.456789

System.out.println( String.format( new Locale("ru", "RU"), "I can into locale: %,.6f", milliSeconds) );
// I can into locale: 123 456 789 123,456789
```

Явное указание локали можно опустить, тогда `String.format` использует значение `Locale.getDefault()`

Comment: Не знаю, результат странный, если использовать nanoSeconds.scaleByPowerOfTen( -9 ); то более похоже на результат.

Comment: Нано: 10^-9, милли: 10^-3. Вы уж определитесь, в каких единицах у вас должен быть вывод.

Comment: В миллисекундах